# How to display 2D bar graph with number of counts on Y-axis and month/day on x-axis in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

I want to plot 2D bar graph in LabVIEW showing total number of counts on Y-axis and Month/day(abbreviated) on x-axis. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Drop an XY graph.
2. Go to the plot properties and set **Bar Plots** to have the style you want and **Interpolation** to be just points.
3. If you open the context help window and hover over the terminal for the graph, you can see the data types it supports. You want the cluster which has a 1D array for the X values (timestamps of a time in the specific day) and a 1D array for the Y values. Generate your data in that format and wire it into the graph.
4. Right click the X scale and select **Formatting...**. In the properties dialog, set the format to be absolute time and to only show the day and the month.
5. Run the VI and you should have your graph.

Comment: My Data is a string data type, how can i add time stamp to this data

Comment: Add some actual sample data or we don't have how to tell

Comment: Speaking generally, you can convert a string to a timestamp by using **Format Into String** with the **%<>T** format specifier (for example **%<%m/%y>T**), but that assumes you already have the time data.